# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.ThreadedRenderer.setStopped(boolean)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, crash

Recently,I got some crash log, here is the full information,Most of them occur on Android 7.0 systems, and most appear on Samsung phones. But I don't know what will caused this error, How could I solve it.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.ThreadedRenderer.setStopped(boolean)' on a null object reference
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3001)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2552)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1537)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:959)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:734)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:670)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:945)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: did you ever figure out the root cause of this?

Comment: I've got this same error, but it's happening on Android 8.0+ for the most part. I did notice there are a few calls to the ThreadedRenderer missing null checks, but that can't be fixed.